# Objective C reference to a variable

Tags: objective-c, variables, reference

I have a list of variables that are named based on two digits then a word i.e. val11 or val26

I need to perform a check on whether a certain value for a variable is equal to the next variable i.e. that val32 == val33

I have the names of the first variables that I need to check in an NSArray (i.e val33)

I can then write a function to perform the check as a lot of long winded if statements

```
-(void)checkValues:(NSArray *)valueArray {

for (int x = 0; x < [valueArray count]; x++) {
    tempStr = [offFiles objectAtIndex:x];
    //split variable name
    NSString *value = [tempStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3,2];
    int numValue= [value intValue];

    //long winded if statement

    if (numValue == 11) {
         if(val11 == val12) {
               //do something
         }
    }

    if (numValue == 12) {
         if(val12 == val13) {
               //do something
         }
    }        

    .... etc

    if (numValue == 87) {
         if(val87 == val88) {
               //do something
         }
    }
}
}
```

Is there any way I can remove the long winded if statement and replace it with a reference to the next variable so that no matter what variable name is in the array I can easily just check it against the next variable

Something like the excel command indirect

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Cell!A",numValue + 1))
```

Comment: It strikes me that your variables named 11Val etc should be an array.  Then you could compare adjacent values in the array.

Comment: how can you have variable name started with number?

Comment: and in general, this sort of thing is better handled with KVC.

Comment: @BryanChen my mistake the variables are named val11, val12 etc

Comment: Your code needs a bit of a tidy up - change the variables that start with a number and also I'm sure your several if (value == x) statements are meant to be 'numValue' not 'value' - since value is your string.

Comment: It would also be useful to see where your val11, val12 are coming from - as really they should be an array or NSArray of their own.

Comment: The values of val11, val12 etc will be set to 1,2,3,4,5,6 based on a random generation.

Comment: Yes, but if you create them as an array you can use val[index] to access them, e.g. val[11], then you can do if(val[numValue] == val[numValue+1])

Comment: @iandotkelly Thanks, I was sidetracked by thinking about creating references to variables dynamically, when an array is the better solution.

Comment: No problem - in the meantime I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is some need for you to store your data in a set of discrete separate variables, this is clearly a situation were an array would work for you.  This could be either a c-style array or one using NSArray - its up to you.

Using a c-style array (assuming 10 completely made up values):

```
int myValues[10] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 }
```

Then your series of if statements can be reduced to one:

```
if (myValues[numValue] == myValues[numValue+1]) {
  // so something
}
```

So if numValue is 3, it would compare myValues[3] and myValues[4] - essentially the same as comparing val3 and val4 in your scheme.  Please note that arrays are zero based - the first value is accessed myValue[0] - so if your numbering scheme is 1-based then you need to subtract 1, e.g.:

```
if (myValues[numValue-1] == myValues[numValue]) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside from the syntax bugs (like starting variable names with a number), what you are looking for is the switch() statement:

```
switch(a)
{
    case 1: // if a is 1 do the following
       printf("a is 1");
       break;
    case 2: // if a is 2 
       printf("a is 2");
       break;

    ....

    default: // if a was none of the cases before do this
       printf("a sucks!!");
}
```

Notice that you always need a break; statement at the end of each case x: